# Tab bar is also moving when i scroll the table view

Tags: ios4

I have written the code programmatically  for my tab bar in my table view.The problem whenever i am scrolling the table view,the tab bar is also moving.The tab bar created in one cell,so it is also scrolling.How to keep that in static.Please help me in this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOn't put the TabBar in the Scrollview. Rather, have the TabBar at the bottom of the main view, and have the ScrollView extend only to the top of the TabBar. That should fix it. If you put the TabBar on the ScrollView, it will scroll around (that's what the ScrollView does).

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating the tab bar as one of the cells, this will always happen. (It's the expected behaviour for the table cell.)

**Why on earth are you using this approach, rather than simply putting the tab bar above or below the UITableView?**

Comment: UITabBar *tabBar = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 376, 320, 44)];
   item1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"TypesToTry" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"crops.png"] tag:0]; 
 NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1,item2,item3,item4,item5, nil];
  [tabBar setItems:items animated:YES];
  [tabBar setSelectedItem:nil];
  
  [self.view addSubview:tabBar];
 
 [tabBar setDelegate:self];                                         this is my code,is any changes required in this

Comment: @ask123 - Where is this code being called? i.e.: What method of what class is this in? How does it relate to the table view, etc. (Also, please don't post code into a comment - you should edit your original question, add it in there and tag it as code so it's correctly formatted.)

Comment: in view did load i wrote the above code,that class is table view class